# How to crack intermittent bug in C Linux?

Tags: c, linux, debugging

I'm running out of good ideas on how to crack this bug. I have 1000 lines of code that crashes every 2 or 3 runs. It is currently a prototype command line application written in C. An issue is that it's proprietary and I cannot give you the source, but I'd be happy to send a debug compiled executable to any brave soul on a Debian Squeeze x86_64 machine.

Here is what I got so far:

1. When I run it in GDB, it always complete successfully.
2. When I run it in Valgrind, it always complete successfully.
3. The issue seems to emanate from a recursive function call that is very basic. In an effort to pin point the error in this recursive function I wrote the same function in a separate application. It always completes successfully.
4. I built my own gcc 4.7.1 compiler, compiled my code with it and I'm still getting the same behavior.
5. FTped my application to another machine to eliminate the risk of HW issues and I still get the same behavior.
6. FTped my source code to another machine to eliminate the risk of a corrupt build environment and I still get the same behavior.

The application is single threaded and does no signal handling that might cause race conditions. I `memset(,0,)` all large objects

There are no exotic dependencies, the ldd follows below.

ldd gives me this:

```
ldd tst 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff08bf0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe8c65cd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe8c634b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe8c5fe8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe8c67fc000)
```

Are there any tools out there that could help me?
What would be your next step if you were in my position?

Thanks!

This is what got me in the right direction -Wextra I already used -Wall.

THANKS!!! This was really driving me crazy.

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded or multi-processed (or doing weird signal handling)? In that case you could have non-reproducible race conditions.

Comment: In most cases, Heisenbugs are caused by (lack of) initialisation.

Comment: Did you try creating a core-dump (`ulimit -c unlimited`, then run your program), and attach GDB after-the-fact (`gdb <executable> <corefile>`)?

Comment: Did you compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and improve your source code till no warnings are given? Did you compile with both `-g` and `-O`; this is helpful to inspect dumped `core` files with `gdb` ... Did you show your code to a colleague and explained the issue? Did you `ltrace` or `strace` the execution?

Comment: Divide & conquer: 1) make a single-threaded version of your program. 2) if you have signal handlers: remove them (temporarily) 3) does the behaviour depend on the input (of course it does!) How? 4) change your buffer sizes (just multiply everything by 2) Does the behaviour change?

Comment: 1) static analysis tools like clang/splint are good for finding the things you forgot to do 2) compile and run it on an OS which does crazy stuff to memory, e.g., OpenBSD with all the malloc.conf switches flipped, to catch bad uses of memory 3) *tell us what the actual crash is*, since you never actually mention it, which is the bare minimum one would expect; "ZOMG IT BORKEN" is not a useful problem report

Comment: It would be nice to tell what kind of warnings `-Wextra` gave you which put you in the right direction

Comment: BTW: in most cases `memset(buff, 0, size);` is wrong: it *hides* bugs. If the program attempts to access memory at buff+size and beyond the program would crash anyway. In most cases it is more helpfull to do eg `memset(buff, '@', size);` to make errors surface *earlier*. Another way to let them expose themselves is "useless" refactoring, eg remove any strcat() and strncpy() and replace them by the corresponding memcpy()s and snprintf()s. If the behaviour changes, you know you have hit a vein (or an artery).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggested in comments :

- to compile with `-Wall -Wextra`  and improve the source code till no warnings are given;
- to compile with both `-g` and `-O`; this is helpful to inspect dumped core files with `gdb` (you may want to set a big enough coredump size limit with e.g. `ulimit` bash builtin)
- to show your code to a colleague and explain the issue?
- to use `ltrace`  or `strace`

Apparently `-Wextra` was helpful. It would be nice to understand why and how.

BTW, for larger programs, you could even add your own warnings to GCC by extending it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/); this may take days and is worthwhile mostly in big projects.

Comment: This may not be the most scientific answer you'll get this week, but the warnings added by including -Wextra forced me to look closer at my code and sort of dive into the problem at the next level. It was actually a refactoring mistake that made me write in a position of an object that was 8 bytes off. The -Wextra stays in my Makefile from now on!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i think that you have some memory problems (see the output of valgrind carefully), cause GDB and valgrind change the original program by adding some memory tracking functions (so your original addresses are changed). You can compile with `-ggdb` option and set coredump (`ulimit -c unlimited`) and then trying to analyze what's going on. This link may help you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug

Regards.

Comment: Basil was the one cracking this for me!!! Thanks again. I'd be happy to vote for you.